# Short sci-fi story about mind control hijacking

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mind-control

I read an excellent SF short story about 20 years ago.  It started as a man being chased by the police.  The man himself had had his mind taken over by another 'being'.  These 'beings' were hunted by the authorities.  At some point the 'being' jumped to a new host and mentally battled with the host mind for control of the body.  The 'being' thought that the host's minds were destroyed during these battles, but as the 'being' got into danger of being caught by the authorities, the previous host minds talked to the being, telling it how to escape.

The twist in the story was that the the host minds actually enjoyed riding along with the 'being', as they got to live and experience things far beyond what they would have otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like ["Murder Will In"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46151) by Frank Herbert. The being you refer to was actually a symbiotic pair sentience, whose two members are identified by "Tegas" and "Bacit".

You can find some pages of that in Google Books' "The Collected Stories of Frank Herbert".

This is the section where the "invaded" being, Joe Carmichael, that Tegas/Bacit has just discovered having survived inside its own taken mind, offers Tegas/Bacit to help in thwarting the authorities by supplying the correct answers:

> "What happens when they resume the interrogation?" Carmichael asked.
>
> "What do you mean?"
>
> "He means," the Bacit intruded "that the true Joe Carmichael can respond with absolute verisimilitude to their search
> for a profile comparison."

Comment: No need to bother Google. The whole damn story can be read at https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v038n05_1970-05_PDF#page/n97/mode/1up

Comment: Thank you LSemi!  That sounds like the one!
Also, thank you to The Lethal Carrot for editing.